# Angular filter not finding object

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm tring to filter out a specific object via a value,

the code I'm using for that is the following:

```
query().then(function (data) {
    var building = $filter('filter')(data, options, true);
    deferred.resolve(building);
}, deferred.reject);
```

but the result is always empty, here is a debug of the values
[image: first image]

[image: second image]

Anyone knows why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: I think the issue is "1" !== 1

Comment: Hmm, could be, trying a cast now

Comment: @PSL yep that was the case,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a casting issue, comparing strings with numbers.